# Unable to get .xml file to load in to .php file using html + javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I don't need anything fancy on this. I'm loading a Q&A page. The Q&A I want on a seperate file so I can just update the file and it will update the page the next time it's loaded by someone.

I created a file "faq.xml" and am trying to load that in to my faq.php file.

```
<p id="xmlp" class="content" style="text-align: center">
    <!-- XML should go here -->
</p>
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        myFunction(this);

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "faq.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(xml) {
        var x, i, xmlDoc, table;
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        table = "<tr><th>Question</th><th>Answer</th></tr>";
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("faqs")
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            table += "<tr><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("question")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("answer")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td></tr>";
        }
        document.getElementById("xmlp").innerHTML = table;
    }
</script>
```

For whatever reason, it's not loading anything. The XML file currently has this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faqs>
    <question>When do you fly?</question>
    <answer>We fly at sunrise weather permitting.  Flights are more peaceful and the winds are great.  We even fly low enough to have a conversation with those less fortunate on the ground.  People tend to hang around at launch and landings to see what it’s all about.</answer>
</faqs>
```

Any suggestions? I'm new to XML (this is my first one).

Thank you in advanced.

---

I put an alert in to ensure the js was getting started and it did function.

```
<script>
    loadXMLDoc();
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert();
        myFunction(this);

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "faq.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Still not sure where the hold up is.

---

I did more testing and I think I found where at least something is wrong...

```
<p id="xmlp" class="content" style="text-align: center">
    <!-- XML should go here -->
</p>
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        myFunction(this);

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "faq.xml", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(xml) {
        var x, i, xmlDoc, table;
        xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
        table = "<tr><th>Question</th><th>Answer</th></tr>";
alert("This one works");
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("faqs")
alert("This one does not work");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            table += "<tr><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("question")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    x[i].getElementsByTagName("answer")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                    "</td></tr>";
        }
        document.getElementById("xmlp").innerHTML = table;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have any information on what's wrong with the code you have. Step one would be checking if the XML file is even requested.

Comment: which one would do how? At this point, I'm not sure what's wrong with the code. No errors or given, just no information is displayed.

Comment: If you are new to xml then you'll find it a lot easier to process xml on the server using php and then output the results via Ajax to the html and Javascript. If you want to fetch the xml document via AJAX then there's no reason to be using php.

Comment: @Hektor I'm using .php for other functionality that isn't server based (includes and such). For argument sake, let's say this is a .html file instead of a .php file. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of loading an xml file via AJAX from https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_xml:

```
<body onLoad="loadXMLDocument('someXMLfile.xml')">

<p>
   <b>Status:</b> <span id="statusInfo"></span>
</p>
<p>
   <b>Status text:</b><span id="statusTextInfo"></span>
</p>
<p>
   <b>Response:</b> <span id="xmlContent"></span>
</p>



<script>
function loadXMLDocument(url) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('statusText').innerHTML = this.status;
      document.getElementById('statusTextInfo').innerHTML = this.statusText;
      document.getElementById('xmlContent').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
```

This will load an XML file into Javascript.
Though as I mentioned, if you're getting to grips with AJAX, PHP and XML all at once
the straightforward way might be to make an AJAX call to PHP and process the xml using a php function on the server.

The 4/200 status codes make AJAX debugging a little easier.

Comment: can you adjust this so a button is not required?

Comment: I've amended the answer to fire the function once the page loads.

Comment: I adjusted it to match my data and it's not loading still. I'll just use SQL and php.
Thanks!